# Why are these transformed canvases not rendering in entirety in chrome at certain resolutions?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, html5-canvas

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f8hscrd0/66/

html:

```
<body>
<div id="canvas_div">
</div>
</body>
```

js:

```
let colors = [
    ['#000','#00F','#0F0'],
    ['#0FF','#F00','#F0F'],
    ['#FF0','#FFF','#000']
]

let canvas_div = document.getElementById('canvas_div');
canvas_div.style.position = "fixed";
canvas_div.style.top = "50%";
canvas_div.style.left = "50%";
canvas_div.style.width = "0";
canvas_div.style.height = "0%";
canvas_div.style.transform = "scale(10) translate(-20px,-20px)";

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++){
    let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = 100;
    canvas.height = 100;
    canvas.style.position = "fixed";
    canvas.style.top = `${i * 10}px`;
    canvas.style.left = `${j * 10}px`;
    canvas.style.width = "10px"
    canvas.style.height = "10px"
    let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.fillStyle = colors[i][j];
    context.fillRect(-0,0,100,100);
        canvas_div.appendChild(canvas);
    }
}
```

Why do the canvases not render over the entire respective canvas element in chrome?

I'm not sure how to word that better. It works fine (as I would expect) in firefox, and it works when the viewport is an odd number of pixels (on both axes).  if you don't see an issue, resize the fiddle or your window (or open dev tools or something).

What I would expect to see (and what I see in FF or with odd sized window):

[image]

What I see with an even width document:

[image]

As you can see, when inspected, the canvas element itself seems to be the correct size:

[image]

Is this a bug in chrome, or am I missing/misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, in the fiddle you provided there are a few errors (should be appendChild instead of appendChile, you need to run canvas.getContext('2d') to draw to the screen, etc). As to the actual question, I believe that you are seeing Chrome's margin/padding. Its the white border that most web browsers give to DOM elements. You can remove it by adding this to a linked css file.

```
div, canvas {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

You can get more information here: [CSS Box Model](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp)

---

So upon more research, the problem appears to be coming from the scale(10) used for the canvas div. I couldn't find an existing solution to the problem, but I recommend just removing it and making the javascript place the canvases at the intended position.

```
...

canvas_div.style.transform = "translate(-20px,-20px)"; // Removed scaling

...

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++){
    let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = 100;
    canvas.height = 100;
    canvas.style.position = "fixed";
    canvas.style.top = `${i * 100}px`;
    canvas.style.left = `${j * 100}px`;
    canvas.style.width = "100px"
    canvas.style.height = "100px"

...

}
```

Comment: Ah, sorry I made a typo in the link.  the link to the fiddle should be fixed now.  it's not margin or padding, both are 0.

Comment: Strange that scale is causing that